# I want come to Jeju Island for 10 days. What is the requirement for traveling?

Tags: visas, south-korea, pakistani-citizens, jeju

I want come to Jeju Island for 10 days what is the requirement for traveling?

I am from Pakistan.

Comment: Please don't post personal information like name and pictures of you in your questions. They are not needed to assist you. Please read up on the rules of the site, "[How to ask a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)".

Answer (score 2):

Nationals of Pakistan are not eligible for visa-free entry to Jeju Island. You will need to obtain a visa to visit Korea. You can find the official [visa application form and instructions](http://overseas.mofa.go.kr/pk-en/brd/m_3158/list.do) on the [Embassy of the Republic of Korea to the Islamic Republic of Pakistan](http://overseas.mofa.go.kr/pk-en/index.do) web site.